# how to compose a new component by using two extjs combobox?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have to use two combobox, the first combobox selects the category, and the second combobox do the search within the category set in the first combobox. I want to package them together to become a new component (having its own xtype, etc). How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define('DoubleCombo', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel', // or Ext.Component e.t.c
    alias: 'widget.doubleCombo',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'combobox',
        ...
    },{
        xtype: 'combobox',
        ...
    }]
});
```

And you can use xtype: 'doubleCombo'.
See this guide for components: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/components

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    alias:'widget.myxtype',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    fieldLabel: 'Label'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    fieldLabel: 'Label'
                }
            ]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```